# How do I change to 64 bit with unity 2017?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, bundle

I have an android build which I want to publish on Google Play Store, but they say my application doesn't fill the requirement of 64-bit. I'm not sure how to change it to 64-bit. Under Build Settings -> ETC2, my options are 32-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit half resolution. My unity version is 2017.2.5f1

Comment: It probably is not an option in 2017 version, because its old, why dont you use the 2019.2 version? (latest)

Comment: You need to change to IL2CPP in the build settings and have the arm64 box checked. All of your plugins must also support 64-bit. That's the basics. This may help: https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/Manual/IL2CPP-BuildingProject.html

Comment: i change it to IL2CPP in the build settings with arm64 checked with unity 2018  and an error appears when building the project  :                        Failed running C:\ProgramFiles\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build/UnityLinker.exe                           Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build/UnityLinker.exe did not run properly!

Comment: That is a different question. You'll need to find your editor.log file and look in it to find the complete error message. If I had to guess you have one or more plugins that do not support 64-bit or you don't have the proper flags set on them to include in the 64-bit build.

Answer (score 0):

Unity 2017.2.5f1 does not support 64 bit APK, Either You have to download the LTS version 2017 or later, and then follow the steps:

1. Once you downloaded the LTS 2017 or later version of the unity then you have to download NDK for unity and each unity will required their own version of NDK for 2019 it required "ndk-r16b".
2. Unzip the downloaded NDK to partition where Android SDK is installed.
3. Now copy the path of NDK which will be "Location\android-ndk-r16b" and past it to Edit->Preferences->External Tools->NDK. If NDK Text Field is not visible then Unchecked the "Android NDK installed with unity(recomended)".[Image reference for the step.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGpcG.png)
4. Now change "Scripting Back end" from "Mono" to "IL2CPP" in player settings. Edit->Project Settings->Player->Other Settings.
5. Now Check Arm 64 and (Arm 32 and x86 if required) from Target Architecture.Edit->Project Settings->Player->Other Settings.[Image Reference for step 4 and 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8qsH.png)

And that it. I hope it works for you.

Comment: i've done these steps completely correct but one thing I'm confusing with it , is these error occurs when i try to build the project no .abb file shown and just i find it in recent files but empty the error is : Failed running C:\ProgramFiles\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build/UnityLinker.exe Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build/UnityLinker.exe did not run properly!  Please i currently searching for a solution but i couldn't find anything solved this problem

Comment: Do you mean you don't have option for .abb file if yes then you have to change build settings form "Internal" to "Gradle" and then you will see .abb  build option. 

and about your second issue, It looks like there is conflict between two files and its usually caused by 3rd party plugins like Admob and Play services. Can you conform which 3rd party plugins are you using? 

By the way if you post this as second question then more people will see it so there will better chance that you will the correct answer but i will try to my best to answer this.

Comment: the option for .abb file exists in Unity 2018.3.12f1 everything works well when i change Build System to internal and the .apk was builded successfully  with gradle otherwise when i try to change it to gradle and building the app bundle checked it doesn't work with that error . it's all about publishing my game on google play cause of this message Unity Export Android 64-bit. The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 2. From 1. August 2019 all releases must be compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.

Comment: Which 3rd party plugins are you using?
From 3rd party i mean plugins not published or created by unity?

Comment: I am using Google mobile ads plugin